# Converting Callbacks Into Promise Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

In order to better understand Promise syntax, I'm trying to convert the following pseudo-code into modern JavaScript.

Here's the old code, featuring the infamous callback hell:

### 1995 JavaScript

```
var floppy = require( 'floppy' );

floppy.load( 'disk1', function( data1 ) {
    floppy.prompt( ' Please insert disk 2', function() {
        floppy.load( 'disk2', function( data2 ) {
            floppy.prompt( ' Please insert disk 3', function() {
                floppy.load( 'disk3', function( data3 ) {
                    floppy.prompt( 'Please insert disk 4', function() {
                        // If Node.js would've existed in 1995.
                    } );
                } );
            } );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Please help me convert the above into JavaScript with Promise syntax (no async/await). I'm a Promise newbie, but here's what I came up with. Is the syntax, nesting and functionality the same as the above code? If not, please help me convert the callback madness into nice JavaScript with Promises.

### Updated Code

```
const floppy = require( 'floppy' );

floppy.load( 'disk1' )
.then( data1 => {
    floppy.prompt( 'Please insert disk 2' );
} )
.then(
    floppy.load( 'disk2' )
)
.then( data2 => {
    floppy.prompt( 'Please insert disk 3' );
} )
.then(
    floppy.load( 'disk3' )
)
.then( data3 => {
    floppy.prompt( 'Please insert disk 4' );
} )
.then(
    // Node.js using Promises avoids callback hell!
);
```

Comment: You can implement promises in 1995. It's just a design pattern. The language didn't need to be modified to implement promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First monkeypatch your `floppy` object with the following methods:

```
floppy.loadAsync = function(d) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        floppy.load(d, resolve);
    });
};
floppy.PromptAsync = function(message) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        floppy.load(message, resolve);
    });
};
```

Now you can write:

```
floppy.loadAsync('disk1')
.then(data1 => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 2'))
.then(() => floppy.loadAsync('disk2'))
.then(data2 => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 3'))
.then(() => floppy.loadAsync('disk3'))
.then(data3 => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 4'));
```

If, as seems likely, you want to access `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4` in the final callback, then you have a [range of options available to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/3478010).

For example, with the "Break the Chain" approach, you might write:

```
var promise1a = floppy.loadAsync('disk1');
var promise1b = promise1a.then((data1) => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 2'));

var promise2a = promise1b.then(() => floppy.loadAsync('disk2'));
var promise2b = promise2a.then((data2) => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 3'));

var promise3a = promise2b.then(() => floppy.loadAsync('disk3'));
var promise3b = promise3a.then((data3) => floppy.promptAsync(' Please insert disk 4'));

var promise4a = promise3b.then(() => floppy.loadAsync('disk4'));

Promise.all([promise1a, promise2a, promise3a, promise4a]).then((data) => {
    var data1 = data[0];
    var data2 = data[1];
    var data3 = data[2];
    var data4 = data[3];
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Extra points for including the .all() example. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Async would be much cleaner.

Write a wrapper function to convert the callback syntax to a promise.

```
const bigFloppyLoad = disk => new Promise(done => floppy.load(disk1, done));
```

Then I guess you need one for the prompt too...

```
const bigFloppyPrompt = message => new Promise(done => floppy.prompt(message, done));
```

Then you can run them in an `async` block.

```
(async ()=>{
  const data1 = await bigFloppyLoad('disk1');
  await bigFloppyPrompt("Insert disk 2");
  const data2 = await bigFloppyLoad('disk2');
  await bigFloppyPrompt("Insert disk 3");
  // ... and so forth
})();
```

Comment: Please, no async/await as stated. This is for learning Promise syntax.

Comment: @GTSJoe - async/await **is** promises. Note how the converter functions return promises. sounds like you're trying to take a big floppy load on my answer.